# Using a variable to query or filter on a dataset in python

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby, subset

I'm using pandas on a project using a dataset that has 21 columns and almost 11,000 rows.

I created a new variable titled `name_ten_plus` that shows the count for column `name` filtered to be greater or equal to ten, using the following code:

```
name_ten_plus = df_name_data['name'].value_counts()[df_name_data['name'].value_counts() >= 10]
```

Using `print(name_ten_plus)`, it shows there are 120 `name` values that occur at least ten times.  The print function yields (as an example):

```
Mike M     22
John J     22
Mark K     21
etc...(stacked under each other)
```

What I've been stuck on is trying to figure out a way to create a subset 
of the original dataset that contains only the rows for the names in `name_ten_plus`.

I have researched how to perform this task in a few different fashions, from using query to the lambda function, and I tried groupby as well.

I cannot find an example that pertains to my exact situation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I'll keep cranking away in the meantime.

Note: I am new to programming, so I apologize for any misphrased language.  This is my first post in this community, but thanks to all previous posters and responders for the assistance and insight provided in these forums.

Mike M

Answer (score 1):

You can take the index from the name_ten_plus Series, make it a set and use `.isin()` to filter your original dataframe.

```
name_filter_set = set(name_ten_plus.index)

filtered_df = df_name_data[df_name_data['name'].isin(name_filter_set)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Koncz.  This worked!  I really appreciate it.  :)